# Django 1.6 - How to short the text displayed into a template?

Tags: django

How do I short an text in django? For example:

I have this text:

```
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

And I want to get:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit(more)`

Where "(more)" is a link to show the entire text.

Can someone help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the template tag `truncatechars`?

```
{{ value|truncatechars:[number to truncate chars after] }}
```

Check out how you'd handle the (more) part [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SLs7q/):

If you actually wanted a link to persist and not just hover, you would probably want to use javascript to manipulate your DOM.

Comment: What about the `more` link?

Comment: You'd do that yourself, it's pretty simple. Place the text (more). right after that template tag, and then use CSS to manipulate it.

Comment: The main thing that you want is the truncatechars method though...
You could add a :hover property to that element that displays the full text when you hover over it...

Comment: Something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/SLs7q/  I did it super quickly just as a proof of concept, and I would advise doing it exactly as I did, but the idea is there.

Comment: You'd replace "sir" with the template tag above, and replace "extra text to be displayed" with the remainder of the variable that was truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 15 (this is arbitrary) is greater than the number you're slicing by:

```
{% if value|length > 15 %}
    {{ value|slice:"-6" }}<a href="#">(more)</a>
{% else %}
    {{ value }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hm, I guess that makes sense too.  The only thing different about your and my solution is that mine would read:  

text...(more)

and yours would not have the ellipsis.

Comment: Also, what does the href link to?